# Getting a raw SQL query from QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I have simple model like this:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And when Im performing this:

```
Something.objects.all().query
```

I get this:

```
<django.db.models.sql.query.Query object at 0xa57b9ec>
```

What is it mean?
Im using newest version of Django (1.5.2). In older versions `.query` was returned a string with the SQL query. How can I get it in new version?

Comment: what happens when you print your `Query` object? `print(Something.objects.all().query)`, What version of django are you on? What environment are you inspecting `.query`?
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L168

Comment: does `Something.objects.all().query.__str__()` work?

Comment: @Alp yep, `str()` is helped. Everything appeared out to be not so hard :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we found out in the comments, that's your answer:

```
str(Something.objects.all().query)
```